# How can I encode Value|Nothing|Undecided in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

Is there a canonical data structure that might contain a value and encodes 3 possible outcomes:

- Value exists (here it is)
- Value doesn't exits
- Answer cannot be given?

I know I can use `Maybe Maybe a`, but these maybes are indistinguishable.

Comment: What is your intended semantics? I guess you'd like your data structure to be a monad, so what should be the difference between "no value" and "no answer" when it comes to sequencing computations? If there is none, `Either Bool a` seems to suffice (or replacing `Bool` with something like `data Failure = NoValue | NoAnswer`).

Comment: `Maybe (Maybe a)` encodes *exactly* what you're describing. Why is this not accepted?

Comment: @AJFarmar I list some reasons you might not want to use `Maybe (Maybe a)` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19073039/791604).

Comment: @DanielWagner Of course there are reasons like those, but I just don't understand what "These maybes are indistinguishable" means. The described structure and nested maybes are trivially isomorphic - what's the problem?

Comment: @AJFarmar I suspect it is an echo of my first point there -- `Nothing` and `Just Nothing` are simply not self-describing, when compared to `DefinitelyDoesn'tExist` and `Don'tKnowWhetherItExists`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I encourage you to make that an answer! I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `Maybe (Maybe a)` is of course that it's difficult to distinguish and remember what is `Just Nothing` and what is `Nothing`. But a bigger issue is that then we can't use `Maybe`'s monad instance, because `join` collapses `Just (Just x)` to `Just x` and `Just Nothing` to `Nothing`.

Assuming we want to use the data type for sequencing computations, as a monad, the question becomes what should be the semantics of "no value" vs "no answer" when it comes to sequencing. If both should just abort the computation, then using `Either Bool` seems to be the best bet. Or perhaps better, create your own data type for representing the error conditions, like

```
data Failure = NoValue | NoAnswer
```

and use `Either Failure`.

An equivalent alternative would be to use [`Except`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT), which provides a [throw/catch](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:throwE) interface.

Comment: when sequencing both "no value" and "no answer" cases just get propagated down the line, whereas the "value" case gets transformed, `either bool` is obscure, I thought there is a standard type for this, well if there is none, then I will just use a homemade one, thanks for the answer

Comment: @AlekseyBykov `Either Bool` (or `Either Failure`) definitely isn't obscure. It should be a standard tool in any Haskell programmer's toolbox. I also don't understand what "standard type" means if `Either Bool` doesn't qualify as that -- everything in that type is in the `Prelude`!

Comment: When you see `Either Bool` in your code how do you know that `Left true` is no value and then that `Left false` is no answer can be given, or... might it be the other way around? This is what I mean by obscure. Standard type is something from prelude that is already there with a set of common utility functions that fits the need out of the box without having to write it, just like Either or Maybe but with more cases

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
Maybe Bool
```

Mapping is trivial: `Nothing` is undecided, `Just False` means that the value doesn't exist and `Just True` means the value exists

EDIT: I didn't know the result value should be available. In this case `Maybe Bool` is not enough and `Maybe Maybe a` could be used. Again, the mapping is trivial:

- `Nothing` means no answer
- `Just Nothing` means that you have an answer but no value
- `Just (Just a)` means that you have an answer and it's inside the second `Maybe`

Comment: I need to pass a value along.

Comment: I would then use a custom data structure. You can use `Maybe Maybe a` but it would be less clear in my opinion than something like `Result a = Found a | NotFound | NoAnswer`.

Comment: Don't miss the parentheses: `Maybe (Maybe a)`.