# Limiting the Types that a Type Paramater Can Take On in Data Declarations

Tags: haskell, types, singleton-type

I'm aware that Haskell has paramaterized data types:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

But is there a way to limit the sort of types that `a` can denote? In particular, I'd like to create a type

```
data Tag a = Tag a
```

such that `a` can take *either* the type `TagPrimitive` *or* the type `TagComplex` (however, I don't want it to be possible that `a` is of type, say, `Integer` or `String` or something that makes no sense in my program).

Is this possible?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused: why have the `Tag` type at all? Are you looking for `type Tag = Either TagPrimitive TagComplex` (or possibly `data Tag = Primitive TagPrimitive | Complex TagComplex`) -- that is, a *single* type which can contain values of either the `TagPrimitive` or `TagComplex` types -- instead?

Comment: Yes, I was confused, and you're right. Is any one of these two alternatives that you mentioned more idiomatic?

Comment: It depends on usage a bit. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19072930/791604) for some discussion of why you might prefer the custom `data` declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed `Tag` type is a bit odd: it is a parameterized type which may be either specialized to a type that can *only* contain `TagPrimitive`s *or* may be specialized to a type that can *only* contain `TagComplex`s. But this seems a bit pointless: we already have the two specialized types `TagPrimitive` and `TagComplex` to serve these two roles.

Instead, I propose that what you actually wanted was a single type that can contain values of either type. For this I recommend cooking up a fresh sum type:

```
data Tag = Primitive TagPrimitive | Complex TagComplex
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

For early prototypes, you might get away with using the canonical sum type, `Either`, as in

```
type Tag = Either TagPrimitive TagComplex
```

but I suspect that as your program grows, this will become an [increasingly bad choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19072930/791604).

Comment: But this type doesn't tell you, statically, which one of `TagPrimitive` or `TagComplex` it wraps, which might be required by OP.

Comment: @Cactus Correct. Which is why I wrote a comment on the question asking about that before writing this answer. But as I point out in the first paragraph: the `TagPrimitive` and `TagComplex` types themselves *do* make that guarantee, statically, about which one they are!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the usual, singleton-y approach:

```
{-# language GADTs #-}

data Taggable a where
  Primitive : Taggable TagPrimitive
  Complex : Taggable TagComplex
```

then define `Tag` as

```
data Tag a where
  Tag : Taggable a -> a -> Tag a
```

then when you dispatch on the `a` of a given `Tag` value, you can just match on the singleton:

```
 f :: Tag a -> T
 f (Tag Primitive x) = ... - here, you know x :: TagPrimitive
 f (Tag Complex x) = ... -- here, you know x :: TagComplex
```

Or, as @rampion mentioned in a comment, you can fold `Taggable` into `Tag`, leaving you with

```
data Tag a where
  Primitive :: TagPrimitive -> Tag TagPrimitive
  Complex :: TagComplex -> Tag TagComplex
```