# Is there a built-in Either parser in the Parsec library?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm looking for a parser that would try to use the first parser, and return `Left a` if it succeeds, or if it fails try the second parser and return `Right b`. In other words, something with the signature:

```
Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (Either a b)
```

Where, e.g., `type Parser a = P.Parsec String () a`

It's not particularly hard to implement it on my own:

```
parseEither pa pb = (Left <$> pa) <|> (Right <$> pb)
```

But it seems to be such a useful and trivial construct that I was wondering if anything similar already exists in the Parsec library.

Comment: Perhaps it was left out from the libraries since its implementation is quite short.

Comment: A lot of implementation are quite short, e.g., `option x p = p <|> return x`. It's my impression that the library is going for a more declarative style with  a lot of built-in primitives to avoid having everybody implement the same trivial functionality.

Comment: I agree. I can only guess that the library authors felt `option` to be so commonly used that it deserved its own binding. Instead, writing e.g. `either f g <$> parseEither pa pb` might be less common than the more direct `(f <$> pa) <|> (g <$> pb)`. Anyway, `parseEither` could have been included.

Comment: In most cases I would guess that people will use their own sum types instead of Either, so its not actually that common.

Comment: Is Either the canonical way to represent a sum of A and B, or is it one of those things that made its way to Prelude but is frowned upon, like String?

Comment: @Gal It is neither canonical nor frowned upon. It is often used for representing "success or error" conditions (hence not frowned upon), but rarely used as an anonymous sum [for sanity reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073039/791604) (hence not canonical).

Comment: I would say that `Either` is as much a canonical sum as `(,)` is a canonical product.